# Acumatica Sales Order Form change item search to prioritize exact match?

Tags: acumatica

So, I'm not even sure if this is the correct place to ask this, but I'm shooting it out there anyway...

We have a list of items, eg: 416r.5, 6r.5, 6r.562. User types in 6r.5, which is an exact match, but also a part of 416r.5 (which, alphanumerically appears in the list before it).

Users say the ideal fix it to only search from the beginning of the field, eg: when I type 6r I only get items starting with 6r, not any item with 6r in it (well, technically they would like the items starting with 6r at the top of their list and all items with 6r in them below the items starting with it. I've squashed that idea.)

An alternate would be that if I enter a number and it matches exactly that it prioritizes. In this case, user entered 6r.5 (which was an exact match), but was moving quickly and didn't see that the first item in the list was 416r.5.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica is generating SQL like the following for the search

```
SET @P0 = '4c645ada-3a08-46ea-acf5-dbdb5d14f635'; SET @P1 = '%test%'; SET @P2 = '%test%'; 
SELECT *
FROM  PMProject
WHERE ( PMProject.CompanyID IN ( 1, 9) AND 2 =  ASCII ( SUBSTRING( PMProject.CompanyMask, 3, 1)) & 2) 
AND PMProject.DeletedDatabaseRecord = 0 AND ( ( PMProject.BaseType = 'P' 
AND ( PMProject.RestrictToEmployeeList = 0 OR EPEmployeeContract.EmployeeID IS NOT NULL ) 
AND 1 = 1 AND ( PMProject.VisibleInTA = 1 OR PMProject.NonProject = 1)) 
AND ( **( PMProject.ContractCD LIKE REPLACE( @P1, '\\', '\\\\') COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci)**
OR ( **PMProject.Description LIKE REPLACE( @P2, '\\', '\\\\') COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci**)))
ORDER BY PMProject.ContractCD, PMProject.Description, PMProject.ContractID
LIMIT 15 /*  */
```

As you can see it is using LIKE with '%test%' which will give back all the results containing test.
I don't think that this behavior can be customized.
In your case the problem is that the InventoryID will always contain the both 6r.5 and 416r.5 and Acumatica is doing search by the KeyField and Description Field.